# How to use 'graphql-to-mongodb' with NestJS (type-graphql)?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, graphql-js, typegraphql

I have the current resolver function:

```js
/********************
* recipe.resolver.ts
********************/
import { Args, Info, Query, Resolver, } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from './recipe.service';
import { FindAllArgs } from './entities/shared/dto/find-all.args';

@Resolver(of => Recipe)
export class RecipeResolver {
    constructor(private readonly recipeService: RecipeService) {}

    @Query(returns => [Recipe])
    async recipes(
        @Args() findAllArgs: FindAllArgs,
        @Info() info,
    ): Promise<Recipe[]> {
        return this.recipeService.findAll(info, findAllArgs);
    }
}
```

It utilizes the current service function:

```js
/********************
* recipe.service.ts
********************/
import * as mongo from 'mongodb';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';
import { InjectCollection } from 'nest-mongodb';
import { FindAllArgs } from './entities/shared/dto/find-all.args';

@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {
    constructor(@InjectCollection('Recipe') private readonly recipeCollection: mongo.Collection) {}

    async findAll(info, findAllArgs: FindAllArgs): Promise<Recipe[]> {
        const queryAstFields = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections;
        let idAbsent = true;
        const requestedFields = queryAstFields.reduce(
            (obj, item) => {
                const fieldName = item.name.value;
                if (fieldName === 'id') {
                    idAbsent = false;
                }
                return Object.assign(obj, { [fieldName]: true })
            }, {});
        if (idAbsent) {
            requestedFields._id = false;
        } else {
            delete requestedFields.id;
        }
        return this.recipeCollection.find({}, {projection: requestedFields, ...findAllArgs}).toArray();
    }
}
}
```

My args DTO looks like this:

```js
/********************
* find-all.args.ts
********************/

import { Min } from 'class-validator';
import { ArgsType, Field, Int } from 'type-graphql';
import { FindOneOptions } from 'mongodb';

@ArgsType()
export class FindAllArgs implements FindOneOptions {
    @Field(type => Int, {defaultValue: 0})
    @Min(0)
    skip?: number;

    @Field(type => Int, {defaultValue: 0})
    @Min(0)
    limit?: number;
}
```

As you can see, I am already attempting to leverage MongoDB's `projection`, `limit`, and `skip` from its options parameter in the `find()` function. However, I've recently learned of the `graphql-to-mongodb` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-to-mongodb). It seems that it accomplishes exactly what I am on the road to doing. I would like to use it; however, I am unsure on how to incorporate it into the way NestJS wraps itself around GraphQL's resolvers, and `type-graphql's` args.

I assume I would have to use it in the resolver, but it has getMongoDbQueryResolver and getGraphQLQueryArgs, and I'm not sure how to add them.

There's an [Apollo Example](https://github.com/Soluto/graphql-to-mongodb/tree/4b295371cb38fe9856f59056ef1c4d782752b5e5/examples) in the repository, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I thought I would try to manually redo everything in the `ArgsType`, but I ran into the issue of defining the type for things that aren't `number`, `string`, or `boolean`; ones that have scalar types already.

```js
/********************
* find-all.args.ts
********************/
import { Min } from 'class-validator';
import { ArgsType, Field, Int } from 'type-graphql';
import { FindOneOptions } from 'mongodb';

@ArgsType()
export class FindAllArgs implements FindOneOptions {
    @Field(type => Int, { defaultValue: 0, description: 'Sets the limit of documents returned in the query.' })
    @Min(0)
    limit?: number;


    // sort?: any[] | object; <-- What to do here?

    // projection?: object; <-- What to do here?

    @Field(type => Int, { defaultValue: 0, description: 'Set to skip N documents ahead in your query (useful for pagination).' })
    @Min(0)
    skip?: number;

    // hint?: object; <-- What to do here?

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Explain the query instead of returning the data.' })
    explain?: boolean;

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Specify if the cursor can timeout.' })
    timeout?: boolean;

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Specify if the cursor is tailable.' })
    tailable?: boolean;

    @Field(type => Int, { defaultValue: 1000, description: 'Set the batchSize for the getMoreCommand when iterating over the query results.' })
    @Min(0)
    batchSize?: number;

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Only return the index key.' })
    returnKey?: boolean;

    @Field({ nullable: true, description: 'Set minimum index bounds.' })
    @Min(0)
    min?: number;

    @Field({ nullable: true, description: 'Set maximum index bounds.' })
    @Min(0)
    max?: number;

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Show disk location of results.' })
    showDiskLoc?: boolean;

    @Field({ nullable: true, description: 'You can put a $comment field on a query to make looking in the profiler logs simpler.' })
    comment?: string;

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Return document results as raw BSON buffers.' })
    raw?: boolean;

    @Field({ defaultValue: true, description: 'Promotes Long values to number if they fit inside the 53 bits resolution.' })
    promoteLongs?: boolean;

    @Field({ defaultValue: true, description: 'Promotes BSON values to native types where possible, set to false to only receive wrapper types.' })
    promoteValues?: boolean;

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Promotes Binary BSON values to native Node Buffers.' })
    promoteBuffers?: boolean;

    // readPreference?: ReadPreferenceOrMode; <-- What to do here?

    @Field({ defaultValue: false, description: 'Specify if the cursor should return partial results when querying against a sharded system.' })
    partial?: boolean;

    @Field(type => Int, { nullable: true, description: 'Number of milliseconds to wait before aborting the query.' })
    @Min(0)
    maxTimeMS?: number;

}
```

I know I can define custom scalars, but is that the way to go about it? The only custom scalar examples I can find are those of `Date`, and with that, I have to define the returnTypeFunction, and I don't know how to tell it to return the same object.

This is the provided example:

```js
/********************
* date.scalar.ts
********************/
import { CustomScalar, Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Kind } from 'graphql';

@Scalar('Date', type => Date)
export class DateScalar implements CustomScalar<number, Date> {
    description = 'Date scalar type; Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.';

    parseValue(value: number): Date {
        return new Date(value); // value from the client
    }

    serialize(value: Date): number {
        return value.getTime(); // value sent to the client
    }

    parseLiteral(ast: any): Date {
        if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
            return new Date(ast.value);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How do I translate, for example, `sort` into a scalar type like the one in the example?